# Mistake in my implementation of Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opticalflow

I created an implementation of two-frame, Lucas-Kanade scale-pyramid optical flow using numpy and OpenCV, but its output seems less “crisp” as the ground-truth images the test image dataset I am using would suggest they ought to be. I feel as if the algorithm has a small mistake causing it to yield “reasonable” results, (e.g. very little movement in areas that don’t have much movement, and there does seem to be some sense of consistency of direction), and the “reasonableness” of the output is making it difficult for me to find the error I made if there is one at all. Here is the code:

class MultiResLucasKanade2:

```
def __init__(self, frames, num_pyramid_layers, scale_factor = 2):
    self.frames = frames
    self.scale_factor = scale_factor
    self.num_pyramid_layers = num_pyramid_layers
    self.calculate_flows()

def calculate_flows(self):
    '''function doesn't "save" any flows calculated right now -- just shows the "flow 
    image" of the flows it calculates'''
    for frame_index in range(1, self.frames.shape[0]):
        base_frame1 = self.frames[frame_index - 1]
        base_frame2 = self.frames[frame_index]
        frame1_pyr = self.build_pyramid(base_frame1)
        frame2_pyr = self.build_pyramid(base_frame2)
        flow_x_pyr = self.build_pyramid(np.zeros(base_frame1.shape))
        flow_y_pyr = self.build_pyramid(np.zeros(base_frame2.shape))

        flow_x_pyr[0], flow_y_pyr[0] = self.get_flows_between_frames(frame1_pyr[0], frame2_pyr[0])
        upscaled_previous_flow_x = cv2.resize(flow_x_pyr[0], frame1_pyr[1].shape[::-1])*self.scale_factor
        upscaled_previous_flow_y = cv2.resize(flow_y_pyr[0], frame1_pyr[1].shape[::-1])*self.scale_factor

        flow_x_sum = cv2.resize(upscaled_previous_flow_x, base_frame1.shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        flow_y_sum = cv2.resize(upscaled_previous_flow_y, base_frame1.shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

        for pyr_index in range(1, len(frame1_pyr)):
            frame2 = frame2_pyr[pyr_index]
            frame1 = self.flow_interpolate_image(frame1_pyr[pyr_index], upscaled_previous_flow_x, upscaled_previous_flow_y)

            flow_x_pyr[pyr_index], flow_y_pyr[pyr_index] = self.get_flows_between_frames(frame1, frame2)
            if pyr_index < len(frame1_pyr) - 1:
                layer_scale_factor = (self.scale_factor)**(len(frame1_pyr) - 1 - pyr_index)
                upscaled_x_pyr = cv2.resize(flow_x_pyr[pyr_index], base_frame1.shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR) * layer_scale_factor
                upscaled_y_pyr = cv2.resize(flow_y_pyr[pyr_index], base_frame1.shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR) * layer_scale_factor
                flow_x_sum += upscaled_x_pyr
                flow_y_sum += upscaled_y_pyr

                downscale_to_next_layer_factor = 1.0/((self.scale_factor)**(len(frame1_pyr) - 2 - pyr_index))

                upscaled_previous_flow_x = cv2.resize(flow_x_sum, frame1_pyr[pyr_index+1].shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)*downscale_to_next_layer_factor
                upscaled_previous_flow_y = cv2.resize(flow_y_sum, frame1_pyr[pyr_index+1].shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)*downscale_to_next_layer_factor

        full_flow_image = self.get_flow_image(flow_x_sum, flow_y_sum)
        Image.fromarray(full_flow_image).show()
        Image.fromarray(self.flow_interpolate_image(frame1, flow_x_sum, flow_y_sum)).show()


def build_pyramid(self, image):
    pyramid = [image]
    for i in range(0, self.num_pyramid_layers - 1):
        prev_pyr_image = pyramid[len(pyramid)-1]
        append_pyr_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(prev_pyr_image, (5,5), 1.0)
        append_pyr_image = cv2.resize(append_pyr_image, (int((prev_pyr_image.shape[1]+1)/self.scale_factor), int((prev_pyr_image.shape[0]+1)/self.scale_factor)))
        pyramid.append(append_pyr_image)
    pyramid = list(reversed(pyramid))
    return pyramid

'''interpolates the first frame to fit the second'''
def flow_interpolate_image(self, image, x_flows, y_flows):
    x_indices_mat = np.array([np.arange(image.shape[1]) for j in range(0, image.shape[0])])
    y_indices_mat = np.array([np.arange(image.shape[0]) for j in range(0, image.shape[1])]).T

    x_map = (x_indices_mat - x_flows).astype(np.float32)
    y_map = (y_indices_mat - y_flows).astype(np.float32)
    warp_image = cv2.remap(image, x_map, y_map, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return warp_image

def get_flows_between_frames(self, frame1, frame2):

    WINDOW_SIZE = 3
    WINDOW_MARGIN = (WINDOW_SIZE - 1)//2

    x_flows = np.zeros((frame1.shape[0], frame1.shape[1]))
    y_flows = np.zeros((frame1.shape[0], frame1.shape[1]))

    frame2_grad_x = cv2.Scharr(frame2, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
    frame2_grad_y = cv2.Scharr(frame2, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
    partial_frame2_partial_time = frame2 - frame1

    for x in range(WINDOW_MARGIN, x_flows.shape[1] - WINDOW_MARGIN):
        for y in range(WINDOW_MARGIN, x_flows.shape[0] - WINDOW_MARGIN):
            frame2_gradx_window = frame2_grad_x[y-WINDOW_MARGIN : y+WINDOW_MARGIN+1, x-WINDOW_MARGIN : x+WINDOW_MARGIN+1].flatten()
            frame2_grady_window = frame2_grad_y[y-WINDOW_MARGIN : y+WINDOW_MARGIN+1, x-WINDOW_MARGIN : x+WINDOW_MARGIN+1].flatten()
            frame2_gradients_window = np.zeros((frame2_gradx_window.shape[0], 2))
            frame2_gradients_window[:, 0] = frame2_gradx_window
            frame2_gradients_window[:, 1] = frame2_grady_window
            frame2_partial_time_window = partial_frame2_partial_time[y-WINDOW_MARGIN : y+WINDOW_MARGIN+1, x-WINDOW_MARGIN : x+WINDOW_MARGIN+1].flatten()

            covar_mat = frame2_gradients_window.T.dot(frame2_gradients_window)

            if MatrixHelper.is_invertible(covar_mat):
                mat_product = frame2_gradients_window.T.dot(-frame2_partial_time_window)
                flow_steps = np.linalg.inv(covar_mat).dot(mat_product)
                x_flows[y, x] = flow_steps[0]
                y_flows[y, x] = flow_steps[1]
    x_flows = cv2.resize(x_flows, frame1.shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    y_flows = cv2.resize(y_flows, frame1.shape[::-1], cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return x_flows, y_flows

def get_flow_image(self, x_flows, y_flows):
    flow_stacks = np.dstack((x_flows, y_flows))

    hsv_angles = np.arctan2(y_flows, x_flows)
    hsv_angles = np.rad2deg(hsv_angles)%360

    hsv_saturations = (np.linalg.norm(flow_stacks, axis = 2))
    hsv_saturations /= np.amax(hsv_saturations)

    flow_hsv_image = np.dstack((hsv_angles, hsv_saturations, np.ones((x_flows.shape[0], x_flows.shape[1])))).astype(np.float32)
    flow_rgb_image = np.uint8(255 * cv2.cvtColor(flow_hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB))
    return flow_rgb_image
```

Some sample frames and algorithm output are here, which were created by instantiating Lucas-Kanade with:

```
op_flow = MultiResLucasKanade2(np.array([bw_base_image, bw_fit_image]), 5, scale_factor = 2.0)
```

[Input frames, algorithm output, ground truth, etc. of running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umERA.jpg)

Comment: This code is really really slow, not sure if most of these `for` loops are necessary. I have the inverse compositional method written up in Python and it takes like a second to run (even less for the pyramidal implementation), but mine outputs homographies so it's a little difficult to  compare. Regardless, the dense flow model doesn't work well for homographies with this image either since so many pixels are stationary (the image is somewhat sparse).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I see. So I should be doing this with only a few points instead (selected by corner response or something, with the math remaining largely the same otherwise)? Also (I assume you're addressing the nested loops in "get_flows_between_frames" as being the culprit for its slow speed), I looked for a way to implement this loop using numpy or some other type of shortcut, but couldn't think of or find anything. I'll give it some more thought. Other than these issues, should the algorithm be working properly? Thanks!

Comment: What's your goal here, to warp points individually with dense optical flow or to create an homography to warp all points together? What paper or source were you working from to create this?

Comment: I am not aiming to solve for homographies, just to find the velocities at each pixel. The source I used was this (links to a powerpoint you have to download): robots.stanford.edu/cs223b04/CS%20223-B%20L9%20Optical%20Flow.ppt. If you don't want to download a powerpoint, I feel this slide best represents what I am trying to do: http://imgur.com/a/vKabB. However, I am not sure if my implementation is correct because the output image (the white image with color splotches) I get does not look crisp like the ground truth (and am not sure if it should look "perfect" either).

Comment: I do agree your results don't look correct. Not sure where the problem lies. Why not try creating some of your own test images to double check it works? Something like a simple salt and pepper image and then just apply some flow (or homography, whatever) to the image and see if the flow field is as expected. Try simple translations first and try narrowing down the issue from there. If you take a look at the Matlab code for reading the `.flo` files it won't be too hard to translate into Python.